# Как отследить закрытие потока FileOutputStream

Tags: android, потоки-данных, java-stream, fileoutputstream

Делаю загрузку нескольких изображений с сервера и запись в память приложения.

Пошел по такой схеме:

В цикле запускаю метод в котором получаю изображение и записываю в файл.

После записи первого файла в память, должна начаться загрузка следующего файла. И так циклим до конца списка.

После окончания цикла запускаю метод который уже работает с файлами на телефоне.

Но, возникает проблема - даже по окончании цикла, остаются открытыми потоки `FileOutputStream`. И на момент запуска второго метода - не все потоки еще закрылись, то есть не все картинки записались в телефон. В итоге Второй метод получает для работы не все картинки.

Делал первый метод `synchronized` - добился только очередности загрузки, но на потоки это не повлияло.

Возник вопрос, как можно отследить момент когда все файлы закачались и записались.

так как запись в файл провожу так:

```
FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(targetImgFile);
```

То первое что приходит на ум - отследить срабатывание метода `ostream.close()`. Знаю что после его срабатывания - все файлы записываются. Но не могу найти информацию как можно отследить что он сработал? Или может кто-то может посоветовать какие-то альтернативные варианты?

====
**UPD:**
Вот класс используемый для загрузки изображения с сервера:

```
public class LoaderQR {
    private Context mContext;
    private String sourceImgPath; //address image on server
    private File targetImgFile; //

    public LoaderQR(Context context, String pathImg, File imgFile) {
        mContext = context;
        sourceImgPath = pathImg;
        targetImgFile = imgFile;
    }

    synchronized public void downloadImg() {

        Target target = new Target() {

            @Override
           public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                try {
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(targetImgFile);

                    if (bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream)) {
                        ostream.close();

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            }
        };

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(sourceImgPath).into(target);
    }
}
```

=====
**UPD-2:**
Тот же код но в в "олдскул" версии:

```
public class LoaderQR {
    private static final String TAG = "Download Task";
    private Context mContext;
    private String sourceImgPath; //address image on server
    private File targetImgFile; //

    public LoaderQR(Context context, String pathImg, File imgFile) {
        mContext = context;
        sourceImgPath = pathImg;
        targetImgFile = imgFile;
    }

    synchronized public void downloadImgOld() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sourceImgPath);//Create Download URl
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//Open Url Connection
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");//Set Request Method to "GET" since we are grtting data
            c.connect();//connect the URL Connection

            //If Connection response is not OK then show Logs
            if (c.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server returned HTTP " + c.getResponseCode()
                    + " " + c.getResponseMessage());

            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetImgFile);//Get OutputStream for NewFile Location

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();//Get InputStream for connection

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];//Set buffer type
            int len1 = 0;//init length
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);//Write new file
            }

            //Close all connection after doing task
            fos.close();
            is.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            targetImgFile = null;

        }
    }
}
```

Проблема та же - не все файлы успевают дописаться.
Подскажите как сделать проверку лучше на  то что все файлы дописались в память телефона и доступны для дальнейшей работы с ними?

Comment: Вообще то Вы сами должны их закрывать, или как у Вас происходит запись?

Comment: Добавил код. Это класс в который передаю ссылку на картинку и предварительно созданный пустой файл, в который будет записана картинка.

Comment: Что за мода пошла - если картинка, то обязательно Picasso/Glide. Почему не скачать их как обычные файлы: поток из сети -> поток в файл?

Comment: @woesss Не поверите, подкупает простота. Но как всегда отсутствие гибкости в итоге портит много крови.

Comment: @woesss Сделал так как Вы советовали - отбросил новшества и получил немного больше гибкости. Но как все же решить вопрос с проверкой на завершение окончания записи в файл?

Comment: Если Вы вызываете этот метод в цикле в одном потоке - то загрузки и записи выполняются последовательно. По завершении цикла всё должно быть уже записано - здесь и можно вызывать  метод который работает с файлами.

Comment: а потоки которые открываю для инпут и для аутпутстим - они то отдельно от основного.

Comment: Нет, `stream` и `thread` - это разные вещи. `stream` - поток данных - читается или пишется синхронно.

Comment: Тоесть стрим запускается в том же потоке? И в таком случае запись в файл с аутпутстрима должна завершиться, и только после того синхронизированый метод может освободиться. Я верно понял?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80241/discussion-between-woesss-and-v-march).

Comment: @woesss оформите, пожалуйста, код который Вы мне скидывали в чате как ответ. Я его приму как полезный. Он реально работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для "олдскул" можно применить `AsyncTask`. Отдаём ему список, он в цикле загружает все файлы и вызывает коллбэк по окончанию:

```
public static class ImagesLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<List<LoaderQR>, Void, List<LoaderQR>> {

    public static interface DownloadCallback {
        public void downLoadCompleted(List<LoaderQR> list);
    }

    public ImagesLoaderTask(DownloadCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    private DownloadCallback callback;

    @SafeVarargs
    @Override
    protected final List<LoaderQR> doInBackground(List<LoaderQR>... args) {
        List<LoaderQR> list = args[0];
        for (LoaderQR loaderQR : list) {
            loaderQR.downloadImgOld();
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<LoaderQR> list) {
        callback.downLoadCompleted(list);
    }
}
```

Используем:

```
ImagesLoaderTask.DownloadCallback callback = ImagesLoaderTask.DownloadCallback() {
    public void downLoadCompleted(List<LoaderQR> list) {
        // всё загружено - можно работать с файлами
    }
};


ImagesLoaderTask task = new ImagesLoaderTask(callback);
task.execute(listOfLoaderQR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятна проблема, но бросается в глаза излишнее закрытие потока, используйте код типа:

```
try (FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(targetImgFile)) {
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Это не решает мою проблему. Данным кодом я могу навести красоту, и урезать поддерживаемые версии андроид. Да и только.

Comment: Этот код в первую очередь гарантирует закрытие потока, а потом уже "красота"  как вы пишите ;)

Comment: Если что-то непонятно написал в вопросе - можно уточнить в комментарии к вопросу, опишу все как понимаю и вижу.

Comment: У меня все потоки закрываются. Да вот только  в то время пока они закрываются - уже срабатывает второй метод который должен сработать только после закрытия всех потоков.